# UI changes in FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.java

Tags: android, multithreading, retain, fragment

I'm using [one of the examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.html) for the v4 compatibility app. I've noticed that in this part:

```
mPosition++;
max = mProgressBar.getMax();
mProgressBar.setProgress(mPosition);
```

if I add a `TextView.setText()`:

```
mPosition++;
max = mProgressBar.getMax();
mProgressBar.setProgress(mPosition);
mStatus.setText(String.valueOf(max)); // here, just to test stuff!
```

it gives up with the following exception:

```
01-29 18:55:08.889: W/dalvikvm(14565): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a791f8)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1035
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:3939)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:701)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6716)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3256)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3110)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3085)
01-29 18:55:08.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at com.mytest.ui.PreActivity$RetainedFragment$1.run(PreActivity.java:111)
```

**Why that happens? Or better yet, how do I adapt the docs example to use a `TextView` instead of a `ProgressView`?**

Comment: There is nothing particular with the text view (hence no full code). It's declared and instantiated together with the progress view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the case of different UI-thread calling up again the `Fragment` in retain. It could be resolved with `getActivity().runOnUIThread(some code)`. Just my suggestion.

Comment: OK, I see that I could run the code on the UI thread... but that's why I used two questions... why can't I adapt that example to a text view without resorting to this method... I mean, what the ProgressBar has that is different from a TextView that I can update the ProgressBar UI element but I can't do the same with the TextView?

Comment: hmm. May be progressbar is not dismissed while fragment goes into pause state. That can cause such error. You must dismiss the dialog when activity or fragment goes into pause state and when fragment resumes the dialog need to be resumed to.